# clustering Objects in Javascript using a custom sort function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have Objects in Javascript that I would like to sort by clustering them based on the distances between them. I perform the same analysis in Java, where I have combined a custom distance function and hierarchical clustering.

However, I can't find any good Javascript alternatives that allow you to define a custom distance metric. I was trying to implement a standard Arrays.sort function, but after determining the distance between the Objects I am a bit stuck on the compare function.

Typically a sort comparator is something like:

```
function comparefunction(a, b) {
  if (a.nr > b.nr) return 1;
  if (a.nr < b.nr) return -1;
  return 0;
}
```

But now I have the distance between a and b based on the overlap between them

```
function comparefunction(clusterA, clusterB) {
  let overlap = 0.0;
  if (relativeOverlapBetweenClusters.has(clusterA)) {
    const relativeOverlapForClusterA = relativeOverlapBetweenClusters.get(clusterA);
    if (relativeOverlapForClusterA.has(clusterB)) {
      overlap = relativeOverlapForClusterA.get(clusterB);
    }
  }
  return 1 - overlap;
}
```

But it's not sorting properly. Also, I see that the compareFunction is only invoked a limited number of times.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with `sort()`. The comparison function just tells it which one should be ahead of the other in the result, it can't control how close they are.

Comment: i was afraid that would be the case, so I need to find something that will incorporate a distance metric

Comment: Or, *shudder*, write your own code to do what you want.

Comment: I think I just found out that my problem matches the traveling salesman's problem. So I'll look into that and see if that can fix my problem. Will look into https://github.com/nikbelikov/tsp-solver

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a traveling salesman problem and it seems to work quite ok. Need to tweak a bit with the distances. Here is some sample code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-davinci-i3tss?file=/src/index.js